# search elasticsearch fields with dashes in the field name

Tags: elasticsearch

EDIT: seems it is an important detail that the field names with dashes have further subproperties which are the ones I am trying to search.

I have some elasticsearch documents with dashes in some field names like this:

```
{
    "item": {
        "item-value": {
            "subvalue": "subvalue"
        },
        "item-name": "name"
    },
    "other_field": "other_value"
}
```

When I try match queries on "other_field" and "item.item-name", hits are returned. Queries on item.item-value.subvalue return 0 hits every time even when there should be matches.

```
{"match": {"item.item-subvalue.subvalue": "subvalue"}}
```

Is there anything else I can manipulate in the query or settings to make this field match without restructuring the documents?

Comment: Are you sure? because I have tried the same it produces correct result. `curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search -d '{"query":{"match": {"item.item-name": "name"}}}'` gives me     `hits": {
        "total": 1,"max_score": 0.30685282,"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "inddex_name","_type": "type_name","_id": "1","_score": 0.30685282,"_source": {
                    "item": {
                        "item-name": "name","item-value": "value"},"other_field": "other_value"}}]}`.

Comment: Please show the mapping of your index. May be `item-value` is a `nested` field.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo. {"match": {"item.item-value.subvalue": "subvalue"}}